# Calculating simple conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

If the probability of living past 60 is 0.8, and the probability of living past 70 is 0.5, how do i calculate the probability of living past 70, given that the person has currently lived to 60 years of age? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia, the conditional probability is given by:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Subbing in the values you give results in:

$$P(\textrm{live past 70} | \textrm{live past 60}) = \frac{P(\textrm{live past 60} \cap \textrm{live past 70} )}{P(\textrm{live past 60})} \\
= \frac{0.5}{0.8} \\
= 0.625$$

Note that $P(\textrm{live past 60} \cap \textrm{live past 70}) = P(\textrm{live past 70})$ since you have to live past 60 to live past 70.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the given probabilities are for a newborn.

Of every $1000$ babies born, on average $800$ will live to $60$ and $500$ will live to $70$.
Now of those $800$ sixty-year-olds, what percentage will live to $70$?